# Unable to detect the reason for segmentation fault?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int t;
  scanf("%d",&t);
  while(t-->0)
  {
      long int size;
      scanf("%ld",&size);
      long int size2=size*size;
      long int a[size],b[size2];
      long int i=0;
      for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
          scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
      }
      long int j=0;
      long int y;
      y=2*a[0];
      for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
          for(j=0;j<size;j++)
          {
              if(i!=0 && j!=0)
              {
                b[i*size+j]=a[i]+a[j];
                y=y^b[i*size+j];
              }
          }
      }
      printf("%ld\n",y);
  }
}
```

I was solving for one of the problems on a popular Competitive Coding Websites, I wrote this code it works for most test cases I tried but, they didn't consider it as it gave them an RE(SIGSEV)->(Runtime error due to segmentation fault.), And didn't even provide with the test case where the error sneaked in, 
I made sure about the semantics of taking Input for data variables of different types and (Even made sure my code stays within the allowed limit of 50000 bytes.) Can somebody help me understand what is causing the segmentation fault here?

Comment: you should use a tool like valgrind

Comment: Your subscript `[i*size+j]` can exceed `size*size`, can it not? You need to look for all occurrences of subscripts for b to determine the maximum value that you need to declare for size2.

Comment: Actually, the bound of b is size2 (which is size*size) so it will still satisfy the bounds I think?

Comment: Switch to `malloc`ating instead of the VLA's as a first step. Large VLA's and segmentation faults are usually related.

Comment: If `i` can reach `size`, then `i*size` is `size*size` and therefore `i*size+j` can exceed `size*size`, no?

Comment: @jeff6times7 `i < size` so no.

Comment: Yes you are right: `(size-1)*size+(size-1) < (size*size)`

Comment: @StoryTeller The outer for loop says `i` can be `size-1`. When that happens and when j >= 1, then the code is out-of-bounds, right?

Comment: @jeff6times7 - No. The math is in Paul's comment.

Comment: @jeff6times7 The bounds of b are size*size, So they will be respected.

Comment: Before `long int size2=size*size;`, suggest `assert(size > 0 && size <= SIZE_MAX/size);` to eliminate trivial errors.  Checking the return value of any `malloc()` is good too.

Answer (score 3):

This segmentation fault is caused by allocating too much automatic memory through VLA (variable-length arrays).

> I made sure my code stays within the allowed limit of 50000 bytes

Large VLAs may cause undefined behavior even if your program has plenty of memory available for dynamic allocation, because they take memory from the automatic storage (commonly referred to as "stack"). The amount of automatic storage available to your program is usually a fraction of the total memory available to your process.

You can fix this problem by switching to dynamic allocation:

```
long int *a = malloc(sizeof(long int)*size);
long int *b = malloc(sizeof(long int)*size2);
...
free(a);
free(b);
```

Comment: The OP can also use a variably modifiable pointer type. And get rid of the hand written indexing. `long int (*b)[size] = malloc(sizeof(long int)*size2);`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the problem still persists, Thank you anyways for making out time to help me.

Comment: @Therebelentropy That is really odd. Try running this with a small example, say, `size` of 10 or so, and see if it breaks. Your indexing math looks correct, though.

Comment: @Therebelentropy Then try increasing the size until you get it to break; it's probably an out-of-memory issue.